# PostgreSQL PL/Python Function for "IF" condition

Tags: python, postgresql

I am using OSM data to run `pgr_dijkstra()` for weighted-path calculation. But after importing OSM data using `osm2pgsql` I populated some additional columns into my `ways` table. So now it has `gid` serial, `the_geom` geometry, `source` integer, `target` integer, `source_height` double precision, `target_height` double precision plus some other columns. The `source_height` and `target_height` columns I have populated using the DEM of the region.

Simply running the `pgr_dijkstra()` on `ways` will give `seq`, `id1` (node), `id2` (edge), `cost` columns. What I want is to also determine the `source_height` or `target_height` for a particular `edge` if the `node` is equal to the `source` or `target`. I was trying to write a procedural function using PL/Python (although I don't know which procedural language is better) but couldn't complete.

---

Following is the attempt to create a PL/Python function. The problem is I don't know how to append all the rows coming from the `for` loop into a variable to return it as a table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test1(source int, target int, tablename text)
RETURNS setof varchar # I am not sure if this return type is correct
AS 
$$
import psycopg2
import osgeo.ogr
statement1 = ("select count(*) from pgr_dijkstra(' SELECT gid AS id, source::integer, target::integer, length_dem::double precision AS cost FROM %s', %s, %s, false, false) a LEFT JOIN %s b ON (a.id2 = b.gid)" % (tablename, source, target, tablename))
statement2 = ("select seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost, b.the_geom, b.source, b.target, b.slope_st_pt, b.slope_end_pt from pgr_dijkstra(' SELECT gid AS id, source::integer, target::integer, length_dem::double precision AS cost FROM %s', %s, %s, false, false) a LEFT JOIN %s b ON (a.id2 = b.gid)" % (tablename, source, target, tablename))
count1 = plpy.execute(statement1)
run2 = plpy.execute(statement2)
len1 = count1[0]['count']
row1 = [];
for i in range(len1):
    if run2[i]['node']==run2[i]['source']:
        # Code to append node, edge, the_geom and slope_st_pt as slope to row1
elif run2[i]['node']==run2[i]['target']:
        # Code to append node, edge, the_geom and slope_end_pt as slope to row1
return row1; # Return row1 table just created using the for loop above
$$ 
LANGUAGE 'plpythonu' VOLATILE;
```

Comment: If it's non-spatial (and this doesn't appear to be), you'll probably be better off asking on StackOverflow.

Comment: Actually, it is an `spatial` table but I have highly simplified my question.

Comment: Let me edit my question rather.

Comment: You don't appear to be referencing the spatial component in your problem. The reason for suggesting SO is because there are a lot more experts in PL and Python there than there will be here, so you're more likely to get an answer (let alone one that works). Although Craig seems to think it's not possible so...

Comment: I think you're better off posting a *properly detailed* question on stackoverflow, with *the error message*, the code you've attempted in PL/Python so far, and an explanation of what you are attempting to do in words.

Comment: Follow-up posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26279364/398670

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan people should not suggest to ask question on StackOverflow only because there is no spatial element in a question.

Comment: (Deleted my answer; given the update to the question it isn't really relevant.)

Comment: @BelowtheRadar - As noted in my previous comment, I made the suggestion because SO will likely get a better quality answer than is likely here due to the nature of it.

Comment: @Everybody: Thanks guys. I have elaborated my initial question. Suggestions are warm-welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Craig Ringer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/12379/craig-ringer) for suggestions.

We don't actually need any procedural function to accomplish the task stated above (In fact it would be an ill-practice to prepare a procedural function for the same).

The following SQL code is equally solving the problem.

```
with x as 
(
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost, b.the_geom, b.source, b.target, b.slope_st_pt, b.slope_end_pt FROM pgr_dijkstra('
        SELECT gid AS id,
                 source::integer,
                 target::integer,
                 length_dem::double precision AS cost
                FROM tablename',
        350, 329, false, false) a LEFT JOIN tablename b ON (a.id2 = b.gid)
        )
select seq, node, edge, cost, the_geom, case
                                        when node=source then slope_st_pt
                                        else slope_end_pt
                                        end as slope
from x
```